# PHP is not showing time proper when i echo from CentOS server

Tags: php, centos

Here is my date when I do `#date` on centos

```
Tue Feb 11 08:58:31 AFT 2014
```

When I use `#hwclock --show`

```
Tue 11 Feb 2014 05:51:00 PM AFT  -0.000766 seconds
```

Here when I use php echo time with the code of

```
<? echo date("h:i:s A",time()) . ' to ' . date("h:i:s A",time()+3600); ?>
```

then I get the result of

```
04:30:39 AM to 05:30:39 AM
```

Here it not not show this time it must show the my current time which is

```
Tue Feb 11 08:58:31 AFT 2014
```

Now if I do `#date*` it shows me right time but if I do `#clock` it not.
Here I have tried timezone I have change my timezone and every other thing
is ok when I have done mistake.

Comment: `<? echo date('r') ?>` will show you what timezone PHP's running in.

Comment: Tue, 11 Feb 2014 04:38:57 +0000 ----result as i am now in Asia/Kabul it about 9:10 if i do #date --- it shows me right

Comment: so PHP is running as UTC (time zone +0). Read this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: yes, here how to change it i mean to disable UTC so it get from system

Comment: just set php to whatever timezone you want. php has this option because very frequently php will be serving up a site whose "user visible" time is completely different from the time the server is running is (e.g. a server hosted in a california data center running a website for an asian audience) - showing california times to asian users is pointless, so PHP lets you override server timezones with different ones, without affecting the server's own time settings.